# How to move buttons to a new line if page is getting smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a group of buttons to move down one line and centered if the page gets smaller. Here's a snippet of my code ...

```
    <div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <p align="center">
        <div class="col-sm-2 centeralign" style="position:absolute;right:40px;top:50px;float: right;">
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="signout" ng-click="signout()">Sign Out</a>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="margin-left: 5px" id="signout" ui-sref="assessment" ng-show="isActive('/modules')" ng-click="hide = false">Assessments</a>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="margin-left: 5px" id="signout" ui-sref="modules" ng-show="isActive('/assessment')" ng-click="hide = true">Modules</a>

        </div>
        <div class="centeralign" style="margin:0">
            <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;"src="images/ceresti-health-logo-500.png"><br><br>
        </div>
        <br>
    </p>
```

When the page is smaller, I want the group of buttons to be centered and uncer the image. I prefer to use bootstrap but I can't seem to get the responsive feature working. The buttons only get smaller when I use responsive.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle demo for this? [Like you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/avtauvyw/) this task should not be a problem.

Comment: Nico, I can't really put out  a fiddle because I can't replicate what I want. I know how to get the buttons to stack on each other when the page gets smaller but I want the buttons to be placed in a different location; in the center of the page and on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for more examples and the bootstrap documentation about the grid system. Plus, nesting divs inside a p element is not the right way to do this.

Also, dont try to override bootstrap margins, paddings etc. Everything that has to do with the grid system, just don't. Often leads to unexpected behavior, so stick with the bootstrap grid styles.

As you can see in the example, i created a container and inside it i've put 3 rows. Remember, always into a container to use rows as a best practice. Inside rows now, i've nested a div that uses grid system classes. Remember, as a best practice, always on a row to put inside div(s) with col-*-(1-12) class. This fixes some margin styles that row has.

To center the content of the grid, use the text-center class. I don't prefer text-center to do my centering for elements except of text, i prefer margin: 0 auto, but this will do for now.

Now, you wanted the buttons to be centered under the img. So you can use bootstrap responsive utilities, so hidden-* class will help you. More info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)
So, I made another row, I kept it hidden from lg, md, sm and only made it visible to xs ( small devices ). I hide the first row ( buttons over the image ) when the device width is smaller than the xs constraint. You can play with the values yourself though, to fix them as you like.

I know, using duplicate content isn't always the best scenario, but it's a fast way to solve your problem, in situations like this!

You can use this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GdmcQs?p=preview).
Here's some code:

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center hidden-xs">
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="signout" ng-click="signout()">Sign Out
          </button>
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="margin-left: 5px" id="signout" ui-sref="assessment" ng-show="isActive('/modules')" ng-click="hide = false">Assessments
          </button>
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" style="margin-left: 5px" id="signout" ui-sref="modules" ng-show="isActive('/assessment')" ng-click="hide = true">Modules
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="http://placehold.it/272x178" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-block" id="signout" ng-click="signout()">Sign Out
          </button>
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block" id="signout" ui-sref="assessment" ng-show="isActive('/modules')" ng-click="hide = false">Assessments
          </button>
      <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block" id="signout" ui-sref="modules" ng-show="isActive('/assessment')" ng-click="hide = true">Modules
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bootstrap row with 2 columns to stack the elements on small screens.

In this code the buttons will appear to the right of the image on medium/large screens and under the image on small/x-small screens. Is this what you're looking for?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MenuController">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
       <img style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" src="images/ceresti-health-logo-500.png">
     </div> 
     <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
       <button class="btn btn-small btn-default" id="signout1" ng-click="signout()">Sign Out</button>
       <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="signout2" ui-sref="assessment" ng-show="isActive('/modules')" ng-click="hide = false">Assessments</button>
       <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" id="signout3" ui-sref="modules" ng-show="isActive('/assessment')" ng-click="hide = true">Modules</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a secondary issue, you have 3 button elements with the same id in your code. You should change these to be unique or you could encounter other problems.

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/ZiDaTOhjPy

Answer (score -1):

everything is wrong! you can't put divs inside a `<p>` tag, you can cause a bug, on rendered html, check it on chrome dev tools, tab elements, and don't put CSS inline, use a class instead. your code are a pain, i can't imagine what you are doing. Bootstrap it's so easy to use, read the docs to use it right.

check it without your `<p>` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8h8te09/

Comment: Lol ok thanks. Will keep these in mind. How am I using bootstrap incorrectly? Just curious

Comment: Don't be sorry, you're helping me become a better programmer! Thanks for the feddback